# Escrever em arquivos em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Eai pessoal.
To precisando fazer um trabalho em C que tenho que criar arquivos com sequencias numéricas e criar um outro arquivo com a intersecção desses números e tal... Porém, eu não consigo escrever esses (int) no arquivo, tipo, tem que ser 10 valores, mas na hora de executar acabo entrando com muito mais valores do que o esperado.

```
    printf("Entre com os valores do arquivo: \n");
    for(cont=1; cont <= *argv[3]; cont++) {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        fputc(ch, f1);
    }
```

*argv[3] é o tamanho que usuário entrou para a quantidade de valores.

Comment: Amigo acredito que o erro de seu código não esteja nesse bloco específico. Não encontrei nenhum erro nessa parte do código.

Comment: Por quê o asterisco antes de `argv[3]`? Você não quer o valor desta posição, então por quê pegar o endereço?

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na forma como está a utilizar o parâmetro `argv` no seu `for`:

```
for(cont=1; cont <= *argv[3]; cont++) {
-----------------------^ aqui
```

`argv` é na verdade um array de strings que normalmente é declarado como:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

Logo `*argv[3]` vai na verdade dar o primeiro caratere do terceiro parâmetro que será convertido para inteiro com base no seu valor ASCII. Por isso se chamar o programa com:

```
programa.exe param1 param2 20
```

O `20` vai ficar no `arg[3]` como um array de carateres, e `argv[3][0]` ou `*argv[3]` vai dar `'2'`, que convertido para inteiro vai dar `50`.

Se pretende utilizar o terceiro parametro para inteiro pode fazer a conversão utilizando `atoi`:

```
for(cont=1; cont <= atoi(argv[3]); cont++) {
```

Para além disso a leitura com `%c` não lé o `Enter` premido, que ficará para a próxima leitura, resultando assim em menos leituras que as pretendidas. Uma solução simples é passar a fazer a leitura com um espaço antes do `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

[Documentação para a função atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)